# side bar with a no previsible width in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

Is there a way to achieve the following behavior in css/html :

[image: description]

Please note the green side bar has not to be responsive but I cannot give it a fixed width with

```
width: XX px;
```

because it can contain more or less elements, so no idea of XX in advance.

The brown bar has to be responsive and takes all the remaining width.

Thanks in advance for any trick! I have tried tables but with no success as we can't specify a div to restrict its with to what is necessary.

Comment: My suggestion to you to forget about brown bar and just use parent bg color instead. So the construction will be parent and one child green bar where you will specify your size and as a brown part will be visible parent bg color

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Posted an answer using `display: table` if you need to support <= IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that easily with flexbox. Here's the example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKXXNE

```
#container {
  display:flex;
}
#sidebar, #content {
  height: 100px;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: green; 
}
#content {
  background-color: brown;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Great solution, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Flexbox**, and if you set `flex: 1` on right `div` it will take rest of free space and width of left `div` will still be dynamic.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.left {
  background: #22B14C;
  padding: 10px;
}
.right {
  background: #EFE4B0;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
span {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left"><span>Span</span><span>Span</span></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

This can also be done with **CSS Table layout** you just need to set `width: 100%` on `.right` div and it will take rest of free space

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.left {
  background: #22B14C;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
}
.right {
  background: #EFE4B0;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
span {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left"><span>Span</span><span>Span</span></div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For older browsers, use `display: table`

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.tbl{
  display:table;
}
.row{
  display:table-row;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}
.content{
  width: 100%;
}
#left_col {
  background: orange none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 1%;
}
#right_col {
  background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl content">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="left_col" class="cell">
      wide&nbsp;content&nbsp;<br>
      content&nbsp;<br>
      wider&nbsp;contentcontent&nbsp;<br>
    </div>
    <div id="right_col" class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice fallback, I think the 1% width is what was lacking in my own try

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this **without using flexbox** can be:

**Working Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/y00e5w6m/
(Note i have used sample css and input just to showcase how this can be done. This should be tuned a bit according to requirements)

Sample Output:

[image]

**Html:**

```
<div style="float:left;width:100%;border:1px solid #000;">
<div id="dynamic-content" style="float:left;background-color:#090;border:1px solid #900">
<div style="float;left;">
Mango
</div>
<div style="float;left;margin-left:5px;">
Banana
</div>
<div style="float;left;margin-left:5px">
Orange
</div>
</div>
<div id="other-content" style="float:left;background-color:#630;border:1px solid #009;">
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var items=["mango","grapes","banana"];
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
console.log(windowWidth);
var dynamicContentWidth = $("#dynamic-content").width();
console.log(dynamicContentWidth);
var otherContentWidth = dynamicContentWidth >= windowWidth ? windowWidth : windowWidth-dynamicContentWidth-20;

console.log(otherContentWidth);

$("#other-content").width(otherContentWidth);
$("#other-content").height($("#dynamic-content").height());
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to have some problem with Firefox, when I resize the browser, the brown container is sent below the green one

Comment: This is done intentionally when the size of your left bar exceeds window size to provide responsiveness to the page else it would create a horizontal bar or would break, if it is breaking in normal case there must be few pixels border or some extra space due to which it might be breaking. You can tune that for sure

Comment: Logic I have used is to keep the width of the left bar dynamic and the right side adjust according to the size of left and window.