# Want to create a side bar fit for all size screens

Tags: sidebar

I want to create a sidebar navigation with an image as background. Image cannot be repeated. So i need its height to be always resizing according to different screen sizes. Please guide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [side bar with a no previsible width in CSS/HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777631/side-bar-with-a-no-previsible-width-in-css-html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use of response css for your sidebar like this

```
@media screen and (min-height: 820px){}
```

or you can use of jquery function method like this

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){ } );
```